# find results containing space to be printed with enclosing quotes

Tags: find, filenames, whitespace

How can `find` search results containing spaces to be printed with enclosing `''` (a quote pair). Only if this result contains spaces, if there are not spaces in the path string, to remain as is.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result? The recommended way of handling "unusual" filenames for further processing is to use `-print0` if your `find` implementation supports it

Comment: ... otoh if it's just for display purposes then at least with GNU find you could do something like `-path '* *' -printf '"%p"\n' -o -print` I suppose

Comment: Even without `-print0` you can reliably do something to a file (with any valid name) thanks to [`-exec`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/108618).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using just `find` if your version supports -printf.

```
find . -name "* *" -printf "\"%p\"\n" -o -print
```

Comment: Note: From Stéphane Chazelas, you may want to set `LC_ALL=C` before this command so that the '*' will match bytes that are not valid characters. That is probably not necessary 99.9% of the time, so I think it should be here as a note instead of in the answer.

Comment: Edited. Thanks, Stéphane. That is probably what most people would want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to generate CSV output, with GNU tools:

```
find . -print0 | 
  LC_ALL=C sed -z '/[",[:space:]]/{s/"/""/g; s/.*/"&"/}' |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

That is, as long as the file name contains at least one `"`, `,` or ASCII whitespace character (including, but not limited to SPC, TAB, CR and newline all special in CSV), translate `"` to `""` (which is how most CSV formats escape the `"`s), and enclose the string in double quotes.

That part is done using NUL as the record delimiter since it's the only byte that can't occur in a file path. And then, we translate NULs to newline with `tr`.

On non-GNU systems, you can always resort to `perl`:

```
find . -print0 | perl -l -0 -pe 'if (/[",\s]/) {s/"/""/g; $_ = "\"$_\""}'
```

After

```
touch 'a b' $'a\nb' a,b a_b $'a\200b' 'a"b'
```

They give:

```
.
"./a""b"
./a_b
"./a,b"
./a�b
"./a
b"
"./a b"
```

(where `�` is my terminal's rendition of that `\200` byte that doesn't form a valid character in my UTF-8 locale).

To exclude `.` and the `./` prefix, replace `-print0` with `-mindepth 1 -printf '%P\0'` (though `-printf` is GNU-specific). Which gives:

```
"a""b"
a_b
"a,b"
a�b
"a
b"
"a b"
```

`-print0` and `-mindepth` are also GNU extensions, but they have since been copied to a few other implementations. If your implementation is one of the few where that still don't have them, you can replace:

- `find . -print0` with `find . -exec printf '%s\0' {} +`
- `find . -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\0'` with `find . ! -name . -exec sh -c 'for i do printf "%s\0" "${i#./}"; done' sh {} +`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by piping the output to `awk`:

```
find . | awk '/ /{ printf"\"%s\"\n", $0; next } { print }'
```